# How to import DataManager from opendap_download module in python

Tags: python, python-import

I'm trying to download multiple MERRA2 (netcdf) files from the following link: https://goldsmr4.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov/opendap/MERRA2/M2T1NXSLV.5.12.4/

I am using the following script to help me: https://github.com/emilylaiken/merradownload/blob/master/merra_scraping.py

It seems to mostly work. However, when I try to run the line

```
from opendap_download.multi_processing_download import DownloadManager
```

it comes up with the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'opendap_download'
```

If anyone knows how to use the opendap_dowload module and how to import DataManager then that would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should place the `multi_processing_download.py` file (from the same merrradownload source) in the `opendap_download` directory, and place the `opendap_download` directory in the same dir where your `merra_scraping.py` is.

Then Python will be able to access it and import the DataManager module.